# Rails - controller to send base64 image to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, base64

Is anyone familiar with uploading base64-encoded images to an AWS S3 bucket from a Rails app?  I recently followed [this tutorial](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/tutorial-how-to-upload-files-using-the-aws-sdk-gem) on using the AWS-SDK gem and it worked very well - the only problem for me is that this addresses the upload from a good ol' fashioned rails form helper, and my upload is coming in a JSON string passed into the controller via AJAX.  Specifically, I need guidance on how to set up my controller so that it gets the data pieced together correctly for AWS.

The `create` controller from the tutorial looks like so:

```
def create
    obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[params[:file].original_filename]

    obj.write(
      file: params[:file],
      acl: :public_read
    )

    @upload = Upload.new(
      url: obj.public_url,
      name: obj.key
    )

   if @upload.save
     redirect_to uploads_path, success: 'File successfully uploaded'
   else
     flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
     render :new
   end
end
```

but mine will need to look something more like the controller below, where the encoded image is part of the JSON string that is the `:report` parameter

```
require "base64"
def create

    @incomingReport = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:report])

     @incomingReport.each do |x|

        hash = ActionController::Parameters.new(x)

        #IMAGE PROCESSED HERE - THIS DOESN'T WORK, BUT IT IS ILLUSTRATIVE OF WHAT I BELIEVE I NEED
        if hash["image"]
            data = Base64.decode64(hash["image"])
            obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[data]
            obj.write(
               file: data,
               acl: :public_read
            )
            @url = obj.public_url
        end

        @new_report = Report.new(report_params(hash))
        @new_report.image_url = @url
        @new_report.save
    end

    redirect_to root_path
end
```

So the controller above is basically what I am trying to accomplish - running the code generates a 'string contains null byte' error pointing at `obj.write(`, though (I wasn't really expecting it to work - I'm certain that it has other problems, too... like getting the original filename...).  Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Just to be sure my data looks correct, here's how the `image` key/value appears in the `:report` parameter (from my console):

```
Parameters: {"report"=>"[{"image\":\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR..."}]"}
```

Comment: I would use something like the CarrierWave gem to decode the string and store it.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that - thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this helpful guide, which looks like it'll do the trick:

http://sebastiandobrincu.com/blog/how-to-upload-images-to-rails-api-using-s3

Comment: I don't have Fog.rb file

Comment: @user3542450 You need to install the Fog gem - https://github.com/fog/fog